# Install ODBC Driver heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, odbc, installation

I can not get rid of the error.

> django.db.utils.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver
>   Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not
>   found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

1. Put

`heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt`

2. Create file Aptfile.

```
unixodbc
unixodbc-dev
python-pyodbc
libsqliteodbc
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql/msodbcsql_13.1.9.2-1_amd64.deb
```

3. Create file requirements.txt

```
...
pyodbc
django-pyodbc-azure
```

4. settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': '',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        'MARS_Connection': 'True',
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix this error I do not know

Comment: Any luck on this mate? I have asked Heroku to help, but it does not seem like they are used to having to connect to Azure SQLServer databases.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be solved with the same methodology as a similar question [Python cant find ODBC Driver on Heroku after setting everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306332/python-cant-find-odbc-driver-on-heroku-after-setting-everything).

**tldr**: the solution was to precompile ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server on an Ubuntu 18.04 environment and copy the required driver files over to Heroku via this buildpack `https://github.com/matt-bertoncello/python-pyodbc-buildpack.git`.