# Python cant find ODBC Driver on Heroku after setting everything

Tags: sql-server, heroku, odbc, pyodbc, buildpack

I have gone through every possible solution on the internet, but I'm unable to make pyobdc get the drivers on heroku.

The steps I have used to create the app are as follows:

```
heroku create
heroku config:set FLASK_CONFIG=heroku 

heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt

git push heroku master
```

I tried even with odbc buildpack but still no luck:

```
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/iFix/heroku-buildpack-odbc.git
```

After going through microsoft website, I trimmed down my Aptfile to instuct heroku to install the following packages:

```
# install msodbcsql17
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql17/msodbcsql17_17.4.2.1-1_amd64.deb
# install mssql-tools
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/pool/main/m/mssql-tools/mssql-tools_17.4.1.1-1_amd64.deb
# install unixodbc-dev
unixodbc-dev
```

This makes pyodbc installation go without error. But when I run pyodbc.drivers(), it returns nothing. The same command on Ubuntu 16.04 returns "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"

The source code for the project is at : https://github.com/IamVNIE/odbcTestHeroku

The hosted app is at : https://pyodbctest.herokuapp.com/

Can someone please provide some pointers to make this work.

Answer (score 7):

I have solved this issue by precompiling ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server on a machine running Ubuntu 18.04 and copying the `libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1` and `msodbcsqlr17.rll` files into appropriate directories via a Heroku buildpack. This is ODBC Driver 17.5 for SQL Server and I likely won't be compiling other versions of this driver, but I imagine the concept remains the same.

The Heroku buildpack and its requirements can be found here `https://github.com/matt-bertoncello/python-pyodbc-buildpack.git`

Comment: I'm running with a similar problem. I followed the same intructions but I still get an error when pushing to heroku. I was wondering if you could share your AptFile along with a screen shot of your buildpacks in Heroku ?

Comment: @ZaraThoustra thanks for opening a new question - I will answer there https://stackoverflow.com/q/69114557

Comment: can you precompile ODBC 13 driver please ?

Comment: I recently updated the heroku stack to 22.04 and now the connection fails

[unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer worked for me until I had to switch to heroku stack 22. After that I started getting the following error:

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

To solve this issue I switched to another library python [pymssql](https://www.pymssql.org/), that handles connections to Microsoft SQL server in azure.
here is a simple example

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server=xxx,\
        user=yyy, \
        password=zzz, \
        database=xxx)
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```