# Flask | Heroku buildpack: odbc | Installating ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server | error on Heroku buildpack-apt

Tags: python, heroku, pyodbc, buildpack

I'm trying to push a Flask app on Heroku which uses an Azure SQL database with pyodbc and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

I followed the instructions from [Heroku buildpack: odbc](https://github.com/matt-bertoncello/python-pyodbc-buildpack) and created the following:

Aptfile :

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
https://github.com/matt-bertoncello/python-pyodbc-buildpack.git
unixodbc
unixodbc-dev
```

Buildpacks:

[image: Buildpacks]

edit :

Following heroku's website, I've added a runtime.txt with the following :

[image]

However when I push the master to heroku (git push heroku master), I get the following error :

[image: error builpacks]

Comment: Try again with only `unixodbc` and `unixodbc-dev` in the aptfile. What are the new logs after `git push heroku master`?

Comment: sorry for such a late response. It worked ! the build has been successful with no errors

Answer (score 1):

If you are using heroku stack-22 (based on Ubuntu 22.04) then this buildpacks might not work. If what you are trying to accomplish is query from SQL server, then I would recommend using library pymssql. then you don't need any buildpacks